# MySQL CASE WHEN mixing [compare_value] and [condition] doesn't work conditions in WHEN blocks

Tags: mysql, sql

> Could someone please explain why this doesn't work as expected. And how to  implement properly this logic on MySQL database? Example below:

```
create table test( effort text );
      insert into test values('0.1');
      insert into test values('0.25');
      insert into test values('1.5');
      insert into test values('5');
      insert into test values('10');
```

> Sql

```
select effort, CASE effort 
    WHEN 0.1 THEN 5
    WHEN 0.25 THEN 4
    WHEN (CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) < 3) THEN 3
    WHEN (CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) between 3.0 AND 8.0) THEN 2
    WHEN (CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) > 8) THEN 1
    END as 'ISE' from test
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You wrote a *Valued Case*, which compares `effort` to a list of values, mysql treats `(CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) < 3)` as a boolean expression, which is probably evaluated to `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix the two types of `case` statements -- simple and searched.  So, put in conditions for each one:

```
select effort,
       (CASE WHEN effort = '0.1' THEN 5
             WHEN effort = '0.25' THEN 4
             WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) < 3 THEN 3
             WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) between 3.0 AND 8.0) THEN 2
             WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) > 8 THEN 1
        END) as ISE
from test;
```

You will notice that I switched the types for equality for string comparisons.  You are storing `effort` as a string, so the comparison should be as a string or using explicit comparisons.

I would instead recommend that you store the value as `DECIMAL(5, 2)` rather than a string.  Then the `case` would be written as:

```
select effort,
       (CASE WHEN effort = 0.1 THEN 5
             WHEN effort = 0.25 THEN 4
             WHEN effort < 3 THEN 3
             WHEN effort between 3.0 AND 8.0) THEN 2
             WHEN effort > 8 THEN 1
        END) as ISE
from test;
```

I see no reason to store the value as a string, if it is intended to be numeric.

Comment: I'm not schema owner. Just make report for  https://trac.edgewall.org/, so it's already defined type for this column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select effort,
       CASE WHEN effort = '0.1' THEN 5
            WHEN effort = '0.25' THEN 4
            WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) < 3 THEN 3
            WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) between 3.0 AND 8.0) THEN 2
            WHEN CAST(effort AS DECIMAL(5,2)) > 8 THEN 1
        END as ISE
from test;
```